# How to set font to ALL of my text field?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have this code and it's working :

```
[_fieldEmail setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"ABeeZee-Regular" size:14]];
[_fieldPassword setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"ABeeZee-Regular" size:14]];
[_fieldRegisterName setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"ABeeZee-Regular" size:14]];
[_fieldRegisterEmail setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"ABeeZee-Regular" size:14]];
[_fieldRegisterPassword setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"ABeeZee-Regular" size:14]];

[_titleLogin setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Raleway-ExtraLight" size:28]];
[_titleRegister setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Raleway-ExtraLight" size:28]];
[_titleVote setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Raleway-ExtraLight" size:28]];
```

also I have this code to apply padding left and padding right for each text field that I have :

```
UIView *fieldEmail = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 10)];
_fieldEmail.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
_fieldEmail.leftView    = fieldEmail;

UIView *fieldPassword = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 10)];
_fieldPassword.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
_fieldPassword.leftView    = fieldPassword;

UIView *fieldRegisterName = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 10)];
_fieldRegisterName.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
_fieldRegisterName.leftView    = fieldRegisterName;

UIView *fieldRegisterEmail = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 10)];
_fieldRegisterEmail.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
_fieldRegisterEmail.leftView    = fieldRegisterEmail;

UIView *fieldRegisterPassword = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 10)];
_fieldRegisterPassword.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
_fieldRegisterPassword.leftView    = fieldRegisterPassword;
```

but I think it's an ugly code. because I have to set every text field and label one by one. Is it any better way to simplify this?

thank you very much..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to loop through all the subviews and check if they are an instance of `UITextField` or any subclass of `UITextField`. If they are, you can set the font property.
I quickly wrote some sample code to show you how you could do this:

```
for (UIView *subview in [[self view] subviews]) {
    if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
        UITextField *textField = (UITextField *)subview;
        [textField setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"ABeeZee-Regular" size:14.f]];
    }
}
```

Be aware of the fact that this code only loops through the 'closest' children of `[self view]` and thus won't modify views deeper in the hierarchy.

Comment: it works bro... thanks a lot..!! will accept your answer as my solution in next 4 minutes because of StackOverflow time limit... ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Make two arrays:

```
NSArray* fields= @[ _fieldEmail, _fieldPassword, _fieldRegisterName, _fieldRegisterEmail, _fieldRegisterPassword ];
NSArray* titles = @[ _titleLogin, _titleRegister, _titleVote ];
```

Then use `makeObjectsPerformSelector:withObject:` to execute a method call on all the array objects:

```
UIFont* font1= [UIFont fontWithName: @"ABeeZee-Regular" size: 14];
UIFont* font2= [UIFont fontWithName:@"Raleway-ExtraLight" size:28];
[fields makeObjectsPerformSelector: @selector(setFont:) withObject: font1];
[titles makeObjectsPerformSelector: @selector(setFont:) withObject: font2];
```

As for the second task you can simply use iteration and put the created `UIView` objects in a mutable array, if you need to use them later. If you want call them by name, then also a dictionary is a good idea:

```
NSArray* keys= @[ @"fieldEmail", @"fieldPassword", @"fieldRegisterName", @"fieldRegisterEmail", "fieldRegisterPassword" ];
NSMutableDictionary* fieldsDict= [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
for(NSString* key in keys) {
    UIView* field= [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 10)];
    field.leftViewMode= UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
    field.leftView= field;  // I hope that this property is weak
    [fieldsDict setObject: field forKey: key];
}
```

Comment: wow... that's a smart solution, bro!! +1 for you... but I got this error message on the console : 2013-09-11 22:37:43.337 Sociyo[521:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[2]'

Comment: It seems like some of your text field IBOutlets are nil. Make sure they're connected in the xib/storyboard file.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't do this way. If you check your code, you have a lot of similar pattern for your TextField.

Why don't create customTextField which is inherited from UITextField? And then, what you need is set font, leftViewMode and leftView in your customTextField class. When use it, just alloc with frame. Done!

Answer (score 3):

In iOS 5 and later you can use the UIAppearance API to give a consistent style to your controls. Which iOS framework are you targeting?

OR

As suggested by Brain you can create a custom TextField and use that instead of UITextField. Your custom TextField would of course inherit from the UITextField but it will change different properties which you desire.